# Determining the best correlated time series

Tags: time-series, correlation

Before asking, I read similar questions, but none of them lead to satisfying answers for my specific interest.

I want to homogenize a climate time series of precipitation of the Dominican Republic over 64 years (1940-2003). For that, it is really important to select a reference series among a group of candidates.

Let's say `sjo` is the base series, for which I want to find a good reference series; `bani`, `plc` and `ra` are reference candidates, because they are close to `sjo`. In the following map, the red point is the base station, and the green ones are the reference candidates:
[image]

I performed three correlation analyses (done in R, function `cor()`), considering these monthly variables: raw precipitation value, normalized difference, and transformed values with Box-Cox. Those variables correspond, respectively, to fields that begin with `p`, `dian` and `pnorm`.

Normalized difference comes from the first difference series method (FDM), which was proposed by Peterson, consisting of:
$[Pm_t - Pm_{t-1}] / [Pm_t + Pm_{t-1}]$,
where $Pm_t$ is the precipitation value for the month $m$, and $Pm_{t-1}$ is the precipitation for the same month 1 year before. I followed [Peterson and colleagues' (1998)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/98JD01168/abstract) remark, which says that FDM applied to precipitation might work better using normalized difference.

As can be seen in page 1 of [this PDF file](http://www.geografiafisica.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sjo_bani_ra_plc2.pdf), correlation was calculated for the whole time series (1940-2003). For raw precipitation and Box-Cox transformed values, `bani` is the best correlated with `sjo` (yellow background cells shows the maximum correlation index). Notice that for raw precipitation, `bani` is significantly more correlated than others. For normalized difference, `ra` is only a bit more correlated than the rest. However, each candidate station has a statistically significant correlation index with `sjo` at the $\alpha=.05$ significance level, suggesting ANY of them could be used as a reference series.

This is a bit confusing, so I was unsatisfied and decided to make a more detailed analysis, splitting the series in 5-year period intervals, and evaluating correlation between series for the same 3 variables: raw precipitation, normalized difference and Box-Cox transformed.

Tables from page 2 to 8 in the PDF show the results of these partial correlations; the last page summarizes the times each station has had the maximum correlation value for each variable. As can be seen, `bani` is the most frequently correlated value for the 3 variables analyzed (in all cases, more than 7 times of the twelve 5-year periods analyzed).

With these results, I think that `bani` is the best candidate as a reference series of `sjo`, but I'm not sure about it. Is the five-year period analysis OK? Should I perform some other analysis?

Comment: Thanks @Nick for corrections, I learned a lot from them. Sorry, English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Your work was already clearer than that of many native speakers! My changes were only cosmetic and technical, not essential. Welcome to CV BTW!

Comment: the correlations are significant, but are the differences between these correlations different? if not, then you can't pick one reference station over another based on correlations

Comment: Thanks @Aksakal for your comment. For the whole period analyzed, and exclusively for raw precipitation, 'sjo' (the base series) has this correlations indexes with reference candidates: 0.650 with 'bani', 0.536 with 'plc', and 0.557 with 'ra'. Is the largest index significantly greater than the next more correlated? Regarding to the other variables, normalized difference and Box-Cox transformed, difference are not large. Should I apply another analysis? What would you suggest me?

Comment: @JoseRamon, I can't answer these questions, you have the data. You can run the statistical tests to see whether the difference is significant

Comment: Thanks @Aksakal for your comment, which motivated me to apply some new tests. After verifying the normality assumption, I applied a `oneway.test` to correlation indexes between variables `pbani`, `pplc` and `pra`; differences were not statistically significant, and a `pairwise.t.test` with Bonferroni adjustment, confirmed it. I also applied a `t.test` to pairs of variables, but differences were only significant between `pbani` and `pra`. I suppose that choosing either `pbani` or `pplc` as reference series would lead to equivalent results. Am I right? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JoseRamon, if the differences between correlation coefficients are not statistically significant, then you can't use the correlations to make decisions solely _based on statistics_. this doesn't make that you can't make decisions at all. you may use other metrics, such as different forms of variables, maybe differences, 2nd diffs etc., depending on your domain. you can also make decisions based on non-statistical argument, e.g. by looking at the map it looks to me that bani is a better choice: it's closer to the coast as the base station

Comment: Thanks @Aksakal. I'll try your suggestions, and appreciate your help. I like geographic criteria for `bani` choice, not only for the proximity to the coast, but also for its relative position respect mountain range and tradewinds, which is basically the same for `sjo`

Comment: @JoseRamon, ideally you want your statistical tests to agree with other considerations. That's why I'd be looking closer at criteria used to identify the reference stations. Maybe there's a better way than FDM. Also, you tried to address the time-variability of correlations by 5-year segments. You could also try to estimate VAR (vector autoregression) like process, and look at the correlation matrix of errors?

Comment: Thanks @Aksakal. I'll try your suggestions and give you feedback.

Comment: Why do you need to choose one of them rather than using all three or using some kind of aggregate score?

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Something like a weighted mean using the three of them?

Comment: @JoseRamon yes, foe example, weighted by inverted distance to rour target destination.

Answer (score 1):

how about you try a Two-Way Anova AND a pairwise test whether with your yearly data and/or the 5 year-period-intervals. You may also do this with the raw, normalized data or Box-Cox data.

Idea is, that you can look for any **non-significant** (for the reference station) difference between the distributions of precipitation per station.

I found this link to be helpful to start your own Two-Way-Anova via R [r-tutorial-series-two-way-anova](http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.de/2011/02/r-tutorial-series-two-way-anova-with.html)

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your answer. I'll try this suggestions, which seems very helpful. I've used it in another research, and is very powerful.

Comment: Hello again @tester1234. I'm trying to perfomr the Two-Way Anova test for my data. Based on the link you suggested me: which should be my two factors? May I say: which variables should I put inside the 'lm()' function? I have precipitation from 3 stations (pbani, pplc, pra), and I want to know which one is best correlated with a fourth one (psjo). I have monthly data that is grouped in 5 years period intervals (data can be downloaded from this [link](http://www.geografiafisica.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/sjo_bani_ra_plc_5yr.csv)). Thanks in advance